# hadoop comparing with previous with out udf

Tags: hive

my input file is

```
2014-08-23       30000
2014-09-24       20000
2014-10-23       50000
2014-11-24       7000
```

I want output like this

```
2014-08-23      30000
2014-09-24     -10000
2014-10-25      30000
2014-11-24      -47000
```

I want to achieve this without udf.
I tried this code

```
SELECT C.ID ,C.DATE,C.VALUE AS CURRENT_DATE_VALUE,COALESCE(CAST(O.VALUE AS INT),0) AS PREV_DATE_VALUE,(C.VALUE-COALESCE(CAST(O.VALUE as INT),0)) AS DIFF_VALUE 
FROM ITEM O 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
( SELECT T.ID ,C.DATE,C.VALUE,MAX(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(T.DATE,'dd-MM-yyyy')) AS PREV_DATE 
  FROM ITEM C 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ITEM T ON(C.ID = T.ID) WHERE   
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP (C.DATE,'dd-MM-yyyy') > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(T.DATE,'dd-MM-yyyy') GROUP BY
  T.ID ,C.DATE,C.VALUE) C 
ON (O.ID = C.ID AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP (O.DATE,'dd-MM-yyyy') = C.PREV_DATE)
```

Comment: How do you get `-47000` in the last row?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a minimal amount of code if you have access to HIVE 0.13 (which has [windowing](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) functions)

**Query:**

```
select date
    ,(value - prev) as diff
from (
    select date
        ,value
        ,LAG(value, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY date) as prev
    from some_database.some_table
    ) x
```

**Output:**

```
2014-08-23    30000
2014-09-24    -10000
2014-10-23    30000
2014-11-24    -43000
```